# Can't get a string item from a JSON response

Tags: python, json

I'm currently fetching data to GET a API endpoint, and successfully fetched it. But, I have an error that this file is not string. I tried to make it like `str()` and `XXX.replace("(", "")`. It doesn't allow me to get an item as `string`.

```py
res = response.json()
## {'timestamp': 1576269528552,'item': {'id': 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'name': 'XXXXXXXXX' }}

uid = res['item']['id'],
name = res['item']['name']
## uid = ('XXXXXXXXXXXXX',)
## name = ('XXXXXXXXXXXXX',)
```

I want to get rid of `(`, `)`, and `,` from this.

Comment: what you getting is tuple, you can use it like `uid[0]`

Comment: Get rid of that trailing comma on the `uid =` line.  I guess you actually have one on `name =`, too, or you wouldn't have gotten a tuple as the result.

Comment: Thanks I got it!

Answer (score 3):

Use `res`, instead of `request`:

```
res = response.json()
## {'timestamp': 1576269528552,'item': {'id': 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'name': 'XXXXXXXXX' }}

uid = res['item']['id'],
name = res['item']['name']
## uid = 'XXXXXXXXXX'
## name = 'XXXXXXXXX'
```

With pandas i can extract them as well:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': 1576269528552,'item': {'id': 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'name': 'XXXXXXXXX' }})
a['item']['id']
# 'XXXXXXXXXX'

a['item']['name']                                                                                                                                                                   
# 'XXXXXXXXX'
```

Comment: Sorry. This was typo. I have a same error yet.

Comment: have you tried: res['item']['id'][0]

Comment: @remotir I added pandas as well, they both seem to work. You can install pandas with pip3 install pandas or pip install pandas, depending on the python version you use

Comment: I did it but it shows like `uid: ('P',), name: ('1',)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I had just get `('XXXXXXXXX',)`...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I had mistaken.

from:

```py
uid = res['item']['id'],
name = res['item']['name']
```

to:

```py
uid = res['item']['id']
name = res['item']['name']
```

get rid of `,`.